# Displaying datetime format in Bokeh hovertools?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, bokeh

I have a Bokeh plot that looks like this:
[image: bokehplot]

I used the following code for hovertools

```
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=
                      [
        ('Time', '@van_timestamp'),
        ('Traffic Intensity', '@aantal'),
        ('VRI Number', '@vri')
    ])
```

where `'van_timestamp'` is a datetime formatted column. My questions is:
Is it possible to display the actual datetime format on hover instead of Unix time code? And if so, How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
HoverTool(tooltips=[('Time', '@van_timestamp{%c}')],
          formatters={'@van_timestamp': 'datetime'})
```

`%c` is the format that specifies the preferred date and time representation for the current locale. More formats are available in the documentation for `bokeh.models.formatters.DatetimeTickFormatter`.